# Qt/C++ QMake define macro with value from CLI

Tags: c++, qt5, qmake

I have an application which needs to use an API key and I do not want to persist the API key within the source code. I want to add the API key during the build step (bitbake process for embedded linux) into the application. The API key would be defined in the bitbake conf and only limited people have access to the server.

*I do not want to do tricks with environment variables set by systemd or something similar, in the end one can read the key either from the text section of the binary or from the service file.* Also the answer to this question is also intended to be used with source revision information which can only be injected at build time anyways.

I set up a MRE like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef API_KEY
#define API_KEY ""
#endif

int main(){
    std::cout << "API key is:" <<  API_KEY << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

QMake pro file:

```
QT += core
TEMPLATE = app
DESTDIR = $${OUT_PWD}
TARGET = test-executable
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

How would I go about overriding the API_KEY when invoking qmake?
I tried all those variations:

```
qmake DEFINES+=API_KEY=my_secrect_key
qmake DEFINES+=API_KEY="my_secrect_key"
qmake DEFINES+=API_KEY=\\"my_secrect_key\\"
qmake DEFINES+=API_KEY='my_secrect_key'
qmake DEFINES+='API_KEY=my_secrect_key'
qmake DEFINES+='API_KEY=\\"my_secrect_key\\"'
```

None of those are working:

```
main.cpp:9:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘API_KEY’
    9 |         std::cout << "API key is:" <<  API_KEY << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it on my phone, but

```
qmake DEFINES+=API_KEY=\\\\\\\"my_secrect_key\\\\\\\"
```

should do the trick. One \ for escaping the string, two more for qmake eating up one pair. And double for the shell calling qmake.